# Qt creator CDB not working

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm using the latest Qt SDK (2.4.0) and am having problems getting the visual studio 2008 CDB working properly.  I have a experienced the following 2 problems which I think are related

1. I have an assert that is failing.  When that assert fails I see the Visual Studio dialog box asking me if I'd like to Abort, Retry, or Ignore.  If I choose Retry, the program does not break as it should, instead it just continues executing.  However, if I put a break point before that assert, and then step over that line within the debugger then when I hit Retry the program does break as expected.
2. All break points that are in place before execution starts are hit correctly.  However, if I attempt to add a break point after execution starts then that break point is ignored.  But, if while stopped, I add more break points, then those are correctly hit.

It would appear that the debugger is only working once I manually stop it with a break point.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit Qt SDK for Windows 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question I guess you doesn't allocate an "object" you use. 
Something like:

```
//header file:
class Foo : blabla
{
public:
    Foo();
private:
    QSomething *m_fie;
};

//source file:
Foo::Foo()
{
   m_fie->IWant2UseItNow();
}
```

if your debugger doesn't work you could try add:

```
#include <QDebug.h>
```

and several print string. i.e.:

```
//source file:
Foo::Foo()
{
   qDebug() << "1";
   m_fie->IWant2UseItNow();
   qDebug() << "2";
   ...
}
```

For your last question qtcreator helps you work less. It does not do something better then other IDE, but it's integrated with qt. It can help you avoid a lot of .pro file configuration. Infact to debug your app correctly you should define in your project file:

```
CONFIG +=    debug_and_release
```

or at least:

```
CONFIG += debug
```

qtcreator does it for your.